# In c# how to get given disk's realtime "Active time" in%, "Average response time"?

Tags: c#, performancecounter

Been trying to get this work but I just couldn't get the exact solution

```
PerformanceCounter disk = new PerformanceCounter("LogicalDisk", "% Disk Time", @"F:");
//disk.NextValue(); <------but this doesn't give me exact Active time%
```

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa394262(v=vs.85)

Comment: @HansPassant I tried your way to check disk usage "string query = $"SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfDisk_LogicalDisk WHERE Name = 'F:'";"  every second. Still not getting accurate it shows 212%, 320%,64%...

Comment: Nvm I had to use "PercentIdleTime" instead of "PercentDiskTime"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the link HansPassant sent me, I developed a code and now it works perfect.

```
 string instanceName = "F:";
        string query = $"SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfDisk_LogicalDisk WHERE Name = '{instanceName}'";
        foreach (ManagementBaseObject result in new ManagementObjectSearcher(query).Get())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Disk usage: {0}%",  100-Convert.ToInt32(result["PercentIdleTime"]));
        }
```

Another solution to my previous code is to simply use "% Idle Time" in counterName paramter.

```
    PerformanceCounter counter = new PerformanceCounter("LogicalDisk", "% Idle Time", "F:");
Console.WriteLine("Disk idle time: {0}%", 100-(int)counter.NextValue());
```